# Define min and max input values on MUI DataGrid number column/cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am integrating a MUI DataGrid Pro as so:

```js
<DataGridPro
  apiRef={apiRef}
  rows={rows || []}
  columns={columns}
  editMode="row"
  rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
  onRowModesModelChange={(newModel) => setRowModesModel(newModel)}
  processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
  onProcessRowUpdateError={handleProcessRowUpdateError}
  experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
}}
```

In one of my `type: number` Columns, I want to enter only a value between 0 and 10.  Input should be invalidated through typing or using the UI up/down controls.

I saw an API option for `columnInputProps` to be added to a `GridColumn` on this page, however cannot find any example usage.  I tried the following:

```js
{
  field: "count",
  headerName: "Count",
  type: "number",
  editable: true,

  // columnInputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 }, // FAIL
  // columnInputProps: { inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 } }, // FAIL
  // valueInputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 }, // FAIL
  // valueInputProps: { inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 } }, // FAIL
  // inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 }, // FAIL
},
```

I suspect I'm misusing these features, as they are more concerned with filtering functionality.

Would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction for setting a min max range on a MUI DataGrid column.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it using the renderEditCell prop and pasing the inputProps directly

```
{
      field: "count",
      headerName: "Count",
      type: "number",
      editable: true,
    
      renderEditCell: (params) => (
            <GridEditInputCell
              {...params}
              inputProps={{
                max: 10,
                min: 0,
              }}
            />
          ),
    
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I needed.  Docs here: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#create-your-own-edit-component

Comment: Should use minLength & maxLength. min & max will not work with latest grid. https://mui.com/toolpad/reference/components/text-field/#properties